# In the Old Republic, where do little Jedi come from?

Tags: star-wars

In *Return of the Jedi,* Luke tells Leia, "The Force is strong in my family. My father has it. I have it... My sister has it."  This implies that Force sensitivity is a hereditary trait.

In *The Phantom Menace*, upon realizing that young Anakin is strongly force-sensitive, the first question Qui-Gon asks his mother is who the father is, which implies that Force sensitivity is a hereditary trait *and the Jedi know it.*

In *Attack of the Clones*, we learn that it is contrary to Jedi philosophy for Jedi to fall in love and marry.  This idea is taken even further in *Revenge of the Sith*, when Padme expresses worry that if the Council finds out Anakin has fathered a child with her, he would be expelled from the Jedi Order.

If Jedi are officially forbidden to marry and have children, and the Order knows that Force-sensitivity is a hereditary trait, this is functionally equivalent to a selective breeding policy to cull Force-sensitivity from the populace, and yet we see plenty of Younglings in the Jedi Temple in the prequel trilogy movies.

If the Jedi are *actively* not having kids, where do all the little Jedi come from?

Comment: When a mummy midi-chlorian and a daddy midi-chlorian love each other very much, there's a special hug they can do....

Comment: The reason the Jedi didn't marry was to avoid creating dynasties of Force-sensitive relatives.  Little Jedi come from random families, and are Force-sensitive by chance, not by design.